# NodeJS - Socket.io Connection to Routes

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am trying to connect socket.io to my routing system, but despite the multiple methods I have read about to achieve this, I'm not sure the best approach with my setup as I have three degrees of separation from my server file and the route file that requires the socket.io configuration. Should I pass it as a constructor argument?

I tried passing the argument `//Routing app.use(controllers)(io);`, but ran into an error with the router module, so I don't believe I'm setting it correctly.

Error: `var search = 1 + req.url.indexOf('?'); TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined`

Here is my setup.

**app.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

//Port Setting
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

//Server Port
var server = app.listen(port);

//External Packages
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var redisAdapter = require('socket.io-redis');
var controllers = require('./app/controllers/routes');

//Routing
app.use(controllers);
```

**routes.js:**

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

router.use('/app', require('./app-routes'));
router.use('/api', require('./api-routes'));

module.exports = router;
```

**app-routes.js (where I would like to configure socket.io):**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var appRoutes = express.Router();

/*====   /  ====*/

appRoutes.route('/') 
    .get(activityFeed.load)
    .post(activityFeed.filter);
```

Comment: Are you searching for get parameters in any route, where did this error cumming from, if not please post the error with sript fle

Comment: That error message above was just from trying to pass `io` as an argument. I didn't get as far as programming it into individual routes. What I am trying to do is make it available within the `./app-routes` module that is routing to all `/app` based route requests. Within this module I was going to have it globally accessible